# 18650 battery concurrency

Tags: batteries, ground, mosfet-driver, ground-loop, dual-supply

I would like to build a small circuit with a photoresistor and relevant ICs that switches a larger circuit that enlights Leds utilizing about 1A from a 18650 5V power bank of new batteries. How safe is it to power the photoresistor circuit with a different brand and older single 18650 of 3.7V that feeds out a "1" or "0" to a MOSFET that switches the lamp circuit with the negatives of the single 18650 and the power bank tied together.

Comment: I suggest you draw a schematic diagram. How do you define "safe"? It's not likely to kill you,